# Is there a way to upload a ERC-20 Binance smart change on Uniswap?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, uniswap, binance-smart-chain

Sorry if this a basic question, but i have a serious doubt.
Is there a way to upload a ERC-20 Binance smart chain token on Uniswap and what is the process to make it?
I'd appreciate your help and information about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uniswap is on Ethereum mainnet, I think you could bridge the tokens but doesn't seem like a good idea. On Bsc you have pancakeswap.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and good suggest. It is a good info